# Why does the control panel require a query string for log-in?

Tags: control-panel, authentication

On multiple ExpressionEngine installs I have noticed that there is a **problem logging in** when the following query string parameters are omitted:

```
http://www.url.net/admin.php?s=0&D=cp&C=login
```

With just `admin.php` alone (or its renamed aequivalent), I get the following error:

> Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the
>   controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

The EE installations affected are set up according to the user guide (but have index.php removed, if that may contribute to the problem).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your EE version but sounds like it might be this bug:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19630

Instead of logging in with "http://www.url.net/admin.php", try using "http://www.url.net/system" instead... NOTE: "system" should be changed to whatever you renamed your system directory if you renamed it.

---

OR update to the most recent version of EE is you are using EE 2.6.1.

Comment: I'm using the most recent version (2.7.2), but this problem has persisted over the last couple of EE builds.

Comment: So query string parameters are just how EE works… but by logging in via the "system" folder, getting them right is non-issue. (Seems weird though having to rename "admin.php" manually if I'm never going to call it directly).

Comment: Wait… [post-installation best practices](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/best_practices.html) recommend moving the "system" folder above the web root… If I were to do so, I'd run into the stated problem, having to login via "admin.php" _along with_ that weird query string.